# ST_ValueCount for multiple bands

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

Given a multi band raster, I would like to summarise the distinct combinations of values found, in a manner similar to ST_ValueCount, but across all the bands rather than a single band at a time.

### Example data

(2 band 3x3 raster) *test_rast*:

*Band 1*

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

*Band 2*

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |

### Summarizing single bands:

```
SELECT (vc).* FROM (SELECT ST_ValueCount(rast,1) As vc FROM test_rast) AS d;
```

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 |

```
SELECT (vc).* FROM (SELECT ST_ValueCount(rast,2) As vc FROM test_rast) AS d;
```

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |

### Summarizing multiple bands:

What I would like to return is the following:

| band1 | band2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

I could achieve this using *generate_series* to index the raster and aggregate the values returned as outlined in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115166/4158), but as the comments to the answer suggest, this is very inefficient. Is there a more efficient approach that I could take?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to this that I have developed, using the ST_DumpValues functionality:

```
SELECT r1val,r2val, COUNT(*)
    FROM UNNEST(
        ST_DumpValues(SELECT rast FROM test_rast,1,FALSE),
        ST_DumpValues(SELECT rast FROM test_rast,2,FALSE)
    )
    AS u(r1val,r2val)
    GROUP BY r1val,r2val;
```